# How do you pass a directory into NLog.config?

Tags: c#, nlog

There is a global variable that the user can set to define where NLog will log files. However, I don't know how to pass that variable to `NLog.config`.

I'd like to be able to use it like `${basedir}`, but instead have it be `${userdir}`. I think this is doable without having to pass the variable using `event-properties` every time I log, but I don't know how. I'd like to define it once when I write

```
static private NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Does anyone know if this is doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to pass (context) information to NLog. I think it this case the "GDC" (GlobalDiagnosticsContext) is the best way:

Set in your code:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("userdir", myDirectory);
```

Usage in nlog.config:

```xml
 <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
         fileName="${gdc:item=userdir}/${shortdate}.log" ... />
```

See [GDC docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: Perfect. NLog has so many features, but when learning it can be difficult to find what you need. Thanks @Julian. That's the second question you've answered on Stack, the third if you include the NLog Git